# Return value from php to ajax error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to return a timestamp variable from php to ajax request if an php error occur? I would like to use a timestamp on the server side and return the timestamp if an php error occurs.

Kind regards / H

Comment: what types of error you are talking about?

Comment: Any error. If the server-side script are being interrupted I would like to return a timestamp from the server to the ajax error function.

Comment: Why not just create the timestamp in the error function or when the ajax call is made and use it from there? Unless there is a massive latency issue it should be close enough for most uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible unless you print that "error" into an hidden div and with $(document).ready() read it out and post that to your ajax.

Comment: Ok, that´s what I thought. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using this code, you can view the php error in ajax

```
 error: function(xhr, status, error) {
           alert(status);
           alert(xhr.responseText);
       },
```

Comment: Yes, but can I return my own timestamp variable to that error function?